# Получение данных из двух связанных таблиц в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Есть две связанные таблицы: Users и Taks

```
  class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;


    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $guarded = false;

 
    public function users()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

Я создала команду для отправки сообщений, мне нужно отправлять данные каждый день по задачам. Письмо отправляет, но вместо имя пользователя сейчас он отправляет его user_id. Как можно получит имя пользователя? Я хотела через массив передавать ('user_id'=>task->users->name), но он пишет ошибку, может сам запрос я делаю не правильно.

```
    class SendEmail extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'emails:send';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

  
    public function handle()
    {

      $task = DB::table('tasks')->where('violation', '=', 'Да')->get()->pluck('user_id');

        $subiect = 'Список';

        $task = array(
            'id' => $task,

        );
        Mail::send('mail4', ['task1' => $task],
            function ($m) use ($subiect) {
                $m->from('test@test12.com');
                $m->to('test@test12')->subject($subiect);
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользовать Eloquent. Замените

```php
$task = DB::table('tasks')->where('violation', '=', 'Да')->get()->pluck('user_id');
```

на

```php
$task = Task::where('violation', '=', 'Да')->with('users')->get();
```

П.С.
Не забудьте подключить модель `Task` через `use`.

Comment: Он берет все данные таблицы task, а как можно указать чтобы вместо поля user_id он отображал имя ?

Comment: Так как в моделе указана связь и в запросе через with('users') она подтягивается, то имя пользователя, по идее, получается так как ты и предполагала `$task->users->name`

Comment: Ну вот по идее да, только выдает ошибку - Свойство [пользователи] не существует в этом экземпляре коллекции.(((

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `dd($task)` и посмотите что в переменной.

Comment: Сделал, передает массив данных

Comment: Два массива: первый из модели задачи, а второй из модели пользователи

Comment: Я поняла в чем дела, я затупила, я же получаю массив, а что бы отобразить надо сделать foreach

Comment: Единственное , вы не сможете подсказать, как можно добавить where для таблицы tasks?

Comment: Да так же... `Task::where('tasks.violation', '=', 'Да')`

Comment: Данные передает, но теперь только по одному пользователю((

Comment: Но без foreach, он не заменяет id на имя(

Comment: Можем попробовать созвониться в скайпе или дискорде

Comment: Ну если не сложно, можно в скайпе?

Comment: Получилось найти?